# python parse from text/csv file to request.post api

Tags: python, json

I would like to turn below curl command into python script. As i need to load the data information from a text or csv. However i have difficulties to parse the data from file. can someone help me to understand this. Thank you.

curl -X POST -d '{"hostname":"localhost.localdomain","version":"v2c","community":"public"}' -H 'X-Auth-Token: my_api_token' https://xxx/api/v0/devices

mycode:

```
import requests
import json
import csv

auth_token = "my_api_token"
api_url_base = 'http://xxxx/api/v0/devices'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(auth_token)}


def add_device(name, filename): 

    with open(nodes.csv, 'r') as f:
        add_device = f.readline()

    add_device = {'hostname': $name, 'version': %version, 'community': %community}

    response = requests.post(api_url_base, headers=headers, json=add_device)
    print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your CSV content. The COUNT shows count of your comma-separated items in CSV file.

```
add_devices = []
with open(nodes.csv, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline():
    items = line.split(',', COUNT)  # if COUNT is 3 then
    add_devices = {'hostname': items[0], 'version': items[1], 'community': items[2]}
```